# SQL Server: how to insert a group by parameter using IF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert a condition at the end of a group by with respect to a condition
in SQL Server.

For example:

```
GROUP BY if(x>Y) parameter1, parameter2 else parameter3
```

Thanks

Comment: What does your SELECT look like when you are dynamically trying to create your GROUP BY?

Comment: @MitchWheat, I think OP required here conditional group by, not dynamic group by. Using `case` expression also we can solve this, but this completely based on the requirement and query. dynamic SQL is not required in some situation.

Comment: Re-opened. Poster: please add more info to your question.

Comment: Yeah i didn't do it dynamically...i had a sub query inside a main select in which i had to group by depending on the value of one of the values in a temp table. The case worked though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression here.

```
GROUP BY (case when x>Y then parameter1 else parameter3 end),parameter2
```

but it completely depends on what else other column you are used in the select part of your query.

Example Query:-

```
SELECT  (case when rank1>rank2 then user1 else user2 end) AS Users
        ,location
        ,SUM(Amount) as Value
FROM    Table1
GROUP BY (case when rank1 > rank2 then user1 else user2 end),location
```

Comment: Thank you so much....That seems to work in SQL server...

I added it like this

Select * from Table GROUP BY p1, (CASE WHEN a>3 THEN p2 END)

so that i can append an additional parameter

Let me just check whether it gets everything and i'll confirm